# How to login user into an application if he is already logged in into another application with different domain name?

Tags: node.js, angular, local-storage, amazon-cognito

I have two applications which has user authentication. Both the applications share the same AWS Cognito User pool. Both of my applications have different domain and even the sub domain is also different. My requirement is when the user logs in into [www.cat.yy.com](http://www.cat.yy.com) and then when he tries to login into [www.dog.xx.com](http://www.dog.xx.com) he should be automatically authenticated because he has already logged in into the other application (Since both the have same creds for the same user).